# How to use LEFT function in COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column that sometimes has B and sometimes B - somecomment. I want to count all instances of B. I expected it to be something like

```
=COUNTIF(B14:B943, LEFT(B14:B943,1) = "B")
```

But no dice. What am I missing? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=countif(arrayformula(left($A$30:$A$38)),"B")
```

What you're doing is trying to sum the relevant values before actually running the `left()` function.

Using `arrayformula()` will let you evaluate the function over the range and use its output as a single number (basically allows you to run the `left()` prior to summing the count of "B")

More about using `arrayformula()`: http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71291

Answer (score 2):

The `FILTER` function has a way with it as well:

### Formula

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A;LEFT(A2:A;1)="B"))
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file: 
**[how to use LEFT function in COUNTIF](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdEJOYkJPaGRRN0R1TjNsU053THpyeHc)**

Comment: I don't follow the notation A2:A. Does that mean "start at A2 and include the rest of column A" ?

Comment: Indeed, else the header will be included as well. Have you seen my example file?